# Using multiple joins for a mysql query

Tags: mysql

Just need some help on doing multiple Joins, its the first time im trying this and hoping it works.

I have 4 tables with data and need to get multiple data from the table.

I have a patient, operation, treatment and data table.

The treatment table has ID's relating to the other tables.

I want to use this table to get the date a patient will have a treatment and what operation they will have.

So basically the query will output the:

> Date
>   Patient Name
>   Treatment Name
>   Operation Name

I hope someone can help me create a query to hopefully get something like this without using pivot tables.

Here is a SQLFiddle with the dummy data created - Feel free to edit this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f3c53

I have tried myself with part of a query but i feel this may need a subquery or different join. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic `join` query, for which you should use explicit `join` syntax.  If you are learning SQL, learn it correctly:

```
SELECT d.date, p.firstname, p.lastname, tt.treatmentname, o.operationname
FROM treatment_type tt LEFT JOIN
     date d
     ON tt.DateID = d.ID LEFT JOIN
     operation o
     ON tt.OperationID = o.ID LEFT JOIN
     patients p
     ON tt.PatientID = p.ID;
```

For your sample data, the operations don't seem to match up.  Hence the need for `LEFT JOIN`.  [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f3c53/8) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM date, operation, patients, treatment_type
WHERE treatment_type.PatientID = patients.ID
AND treatment_type.OperationID = operation.ID
AND treatment_type.DateID = date.ID
```